# Is it possible to set a default null value for columns in JPA, and if, how is it done using annotations?

Tags: java, jpa

```
@Column(name = "price", nullable = "true")
private Double PriceAmount ;.
```

Till now i tried this and i got the exception

```
 Caused by: <openjpa-2.1.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1497841 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Field "com.model.entities.jpa.Price.PriceAmount" of "com.model.entities.jpa.Price@1433836" can not be set to "null" value.
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.HandlerFieldStrategy.insert(HandlerFieldStrategy.java:133)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.insert(FieldMapping.java:623)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.insert(AbstractUpdateManager.java:239)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.populateRowManager(AbstractUpdateManager.java:166)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:97)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:78)
```

Comment: Is your column nullable on DB?

Comment: Yes @Jürgen the table column is also null? "Y"

Answer (score 0):

JPA Columns can only be set as null if the Table Columns NULL as well. Please check in the database and change it.

Comment: Yes table column is also null. It is written like null? "Y".
so that means it can accept null

Comment: Could you provide more details? The Table create script, the JPA Entity and the full stack trace?

Comment: Could please check i provide all details.

Answer (score 0):

Using the annotation

```
@Column(insertable = false)

private String column= null;
```

will prevent the field property to be added to the SQL. And then the fielddefault value will be use.